# How pass a parameter to IN Operator?

Tags: c#, oracle, nhibernate, ora-00932

I'm Trying, pass a long array for a named query (native SQL) for to use in an IN STATEMENT:
Like this:

(...)
WHERE Identificator IN (:pIdes)

I tried pass my ides as long[]:

```
 ctx.GetNamedQuery("NamedQueryName")                                          
                   .SetParameter<long[]>("pIdes", Identificators)
                   .List<EmpreendimentoInputReport>();
```

and as a string

```
 ctx.GetNamedQuery("NamedQueryName")                                          
                   .SetParameter<string>("pIdes", Identificators)
                   .List<EmpreendimentoInputReport>();
```

When the parameter is a string return nothing, whem is a long[] return this Oracle error:

"Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException: ORA-00932: tipos de dados inconsistentes: esperava NUMBER obteve BINARY"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388021/parameterizing-a-hql-in-clause-using-hqlbasedquery

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `SetParameterList` instead of `SetParameter`.